# Apache Camel S3 only do polling once

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am currently having issue with my camel S3 route

aws-s3://myBucket?amazonS3Client=#amazonS3Client&prefix=myFolder&delay=5000

The polling happen once and the file inside myFolder consumed correctly.

But after that there are no more polling happen.

Then I tried to debug org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Consumer.java class inside method poll() there is check for filesConsumed variable which is always true seems.

Could you please advise?

Many Thanks

Comment: I am currently using Apache Camel AWS component version 2.16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the version to 2.16.0 and it works finally.